# Selecting rows based on MAX and MIN Date

Tags: mysql, sql

My data looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE hhmonthlyprogress (
  prgid INT,
  hhid INT,  
  frdate DATETIME,
  assetdate DATETIME,
  liftranche1 INT,
  liftranche2 INT,
  lgaf INT,
  sifdate DATETIME,
  sif INT
);

INSERT INTO hhmonthlyprogress VALUES
(63439,22,"24/09/2021 10:24","04/08/2018 18:30",20000,0,7000,\N,10000),
(183359,22,"10/12/2021 08:02","04/08/2018 07:30",20000,0,7000,"08/03/2020 18:30",10000),
(664507,22,"03/06/2022 14:28","04/08/2018 02:00",20000,0,7000,"08/03/2021 18:30",10000),
(1005631,22,"10/08/2022 13:16","03/08/2018 20:30",20000,0,7000,"08/03/2021 13:00",10000),
(1429489,22,"04/11/2022 13:17",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(466218,24,"05/04/2022 15:19",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(1503111,24,"09/11/2022 15:46",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(80468,69,"06/10/2021 09:24","14/03/2019 18:30",20000,0,7000,\N,10000),
(176418,69,"08/12/2021 08:08","14/03/2019 13:00",20000,0,7000,"09/02/2020 18:30",10000),
(222523,69,"05/01/2022 11:18","14/03/2019 07:30",20000,0,7000,"09/03/2020 18:30",10000),
(275730,69,"02/02/2022 09:44","14/03/2019 02:00",20000,0,7000,"09/05/2020 18:30",10000),
(345593,69,"02/03/2022 08:09","13/03/2019 20:30",20000,0,7000,"09/03/2020 18:30",10000),
(477515,69,"06/04/2022 15:05","13/03/2019 15:00",20000,0,7000,"09/10/2020 18:30",10000),
(555184,69,"04/05/2022 14:25","13/03/2019 09:30",20000,0,7000,"09/03/2020 18:30",10000),
(638225,69,"01/06/2022 14:14","13/03/2019 04:00",20000,0,7000,"09/03/2020 18:30",10000),
(1009932,69,"11/08/2022 11:52","12/03/2019 22:30",20000,0,7000,"09/03/2020 13:00",10000),
(1020086,69,"13/08/2022 18:47","12/03/2019 17:00",20000,0,7000,"09/03/2020 07:30",10000),
(1154548,69,"07/09/2022 14:03","12/03/2019 11:30",20000,0,7000,"09/03/2020 02:00",10000),
(1341705,69,"12/10/2022 17:12","12/03/2019 06:00",20000,0,7000,"08/03/2020 20:30",10000),
(1390179,69,"02/11/2022 14:01","12/03/2019 00:30",20000,0,7000,"08/03/2020 15:00",10000),
(96005,10,"19/10/2021 06:36","18/10/2021 18:30",20000,0,7000,\N,10000),
(176802,10,"08/12/2021 08:49",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(221886,10,"05/01/2022 10:25",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(274859,10,"02/02/2022 08:50",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(478673,10,"06/04/2022 16:11",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(559896,10,"04/05/2022 18:00",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(641063,10,"01/06/2022 16:59",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(833177,10,"06/07/2022 17:34",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N),
(931901,10,"04/08/2022 11:48",\N,\N,\N,\N,"09/03/2020 13:00",10000),
(1172888,10,"08/09/2022 18:41",\N,\N,\N,\N,"10/04/2020 13:00",10000),
(1336712,10,"11/10/2022 20:06",\N,\N,\N,\N,"11/05/2020 13:00",10000),
(1342471,10,"12/10/2022 21:45",\N,\N,\N,\N,"12/06/2020 13:00",10000),
(1477822,10,"07/11/2022 14:32",\N,\N,\N,\N,"13/07/2020 13:00",10000)
```

To explain the data, every `prgid` is unique. The `hhid` should be unique for every month, but in some cases there can be multiple entries. `frdate` is the date when the row is entered. It is possible that `assetdate` is /N, but there is liftranch1 associated with it. Similar logic applies to `sifdate` and `sif`. The code I tried is this:

```sql
SELECT hhid, frdate, DATE(sifdate) AS sif_date, sif,  
DATE(assetdate) AS lif_date, lif, liftranch1,
 liftranch2, lgaf
FROM mprog
WHERE prgid 
IN (
SELECT MAX(prgid) FROM mprog
GROUP BY hhid)
```

My query rejects the hhid where prgid in not max.

The expected output is mentioned below:

```
prgid    hhid   max(frdate) min(assetdate)  liftranche1 liftranch2  lgaf    min(sifdate)    sif
1429489 22  10/08/2022 13:16    03/08/2018 20:30    20000   0   7000    08/03/2020 18:30    10000
1503111 24  09/11/2022 15:46    \N                    \N    \N    \N          \N             \N
1390179 69  02/11/2022 14:01    14/03/2019 18:30    20000   0   7000    09/02/2020 18:30    10000
1477822 10  07/11/2022 14:32    \N                    \N    \N  \N      09/03/2020 13:00    10000
```

The expected output is unique `hhid`for `max(fradate)` where `liftranch1`,`liftranch2`and`lgaf`should have a number.Similarily with `min(sifdate)`  and `sif` for that `hhid`.

Comment: Did you mean to exclude prgid=1429489 from your expected result? If so, why? You probably should make prgid your primary key.

Comment: Sry for the mistake.I hope this solves it...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want to do is select all columns from each row in the table with the maximum prgid value for each group of hhid, you can do the following...

```
SELECT A.*
FROM hhmonthlyprogress A
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(B.prgid) AS maxprgid, B.hhid
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress B
  GROUP BY B.hhid 
  ) C ON C.maxprgid = A.prgid;
```

For a large table, it is probably a good idea to set up prgid as the primary key because you said this column is unique.